# getting a number correct on 3 successive dice rolls

Tags: probability

I'm working through some practice problems. If we guess a number between $1..6$ and then roll 3 regular six sided die, what is the probability that our guess will appear on any of the dice?

I'm new to probability and I'm struggling a bit to understand this....
I know it's not 1/6 * 3 or $(1/6)^3$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hint:  it's easier to find the probability that your guess is not on any of the dice.

Comment: Thanks Lulu. That's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the possible number of total outcomes? There are three dices each may give $6$ numbers that is:

$6^3$

What is the possible number of desired outcomes?

Notice that you said that you want $6$ to appear anywhere, so we might just go about and find the number of not desired outcomes. A common practice, btw. Well, that is the same as if we would not want $6$ to appear anywhere, which is the same as the number of outcome on $3$ $5$-side dices, with $6$'s removed, and if so these now have

$5^3$ outcomes.

That leaves $6^3$ - $5^3$ and the probability is then the number of desired outcomes divided by the number of total outcomes.

$$ \frac{6^3 - 5^3}{6^3} $$

You do the math. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much @Alexander this makes sense!